# Lose dictionary values in a list after clearing dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

In a for loop, I add data to few dictionaries, and I need to keep a running list of these dictionaries and their values, so at the end of the for loop, I add these dicts to a list.  Now that I'm done with the dicts, I need to reuse them for the next iteration, so I dict.clear().  However, doing that also nukes the values of the dicts already in the list.  I think I now understand that I'm only passing a reference to the dictionaries and not the values.

I can't let the dicts grow because each one will represent a row in a db.

How can I pass in values and not references so they stay permanently in my list and allow my list to grow?

I'm sure this is a duplicate of an existing question (the closest I've found is deep and shallow copying), but I haven't found it - probably because I don't know how to phrase the question properly.  Compounded by I've only been writing Python for a few months.

```
dict1 = {1:'a', 2:'b'}
dict2 = {24:'x',25:'y'}
list1 = dict1, dict2
for l in list1:
    for keys, values in l.items():
        print('key: {}, value: {}'.format(keys, values))

dict1.clear()
dict2.clear()
for l in list1:
    for keys, values in l.items():
        print('keys {}, values {}'.format(keys, values))
print(list1)

key: 1, value: a
key: 2, value: b
key: 24, value: x
key: 25, value: y
({}, {})

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I expect to see those 4 rows repeated.  At least that's what I desire :-)
Also tried:

```
#list1.append(dict1.copy())
#list1.append(dict2.copy())
list1.append(copy.deepcopy(dict1))
list1.append(copy.deepcopy(dict2))
```

> ok, progress.  I've changed it up, thanks to the suggestion, to:

```
dict1 = {1:'a', 2:'b'}
dict2 = {24:'x',25:'y'}
list1 = [dict1, dict2]

list1.append(copy.deepcopy(dict1))
list1.append(copy.deepcopy(dict2))

dict1.clear()
dict2.clear()
for l in list1:
    for keys, values in l.items():
        print('keys {}, values {}'.format(keys, values))
print('Dicts in list: ',len(list1))
print(list1)

# and get this:
Dicts in list:  4
[{}, {}, {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}, {24: 'x', 25: 'y'}]
```

So I did not lose my values now, and that's what I want, but I do show two empty dictionaries.  I believe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: What you are calling a list is really a tuple. Since you know about copying, why not just put copies of the dictionaries in the list?

Comment: Oh, am I doing this wrong? list1 = dict1, dict2

Comment: Yes, that makes it a tuple. Put square brackets around it.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing the dict1 and dict2 after you've copied them. Those two empty dictionaries you're seeing are the dict1 and dict2 you add at the beginning of your script:

```
dict1 = {1:'a', 2:'b'}
dict2 = {24:'x',25:'y'}
list1 = [dict1, dict2]
```

Here you're adding the dicts to the list, you then do a deepcopy which adds copies of those two dicts to the list, then you are calling:

```
dict1.clear()
dict2.clear()
```

When you add a dict to a list, it does not make a copy, it's simply a reference to the original dict, so if you modify that original dict via `clear()` all references to that dict will show an empty dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a fairly old question, but I was actually struggling with a similar issue.
In your situation, you pretty much got there, the only thing I'd change to make it work as you expect:

```
list1 = [copy.deepcopy(dict1), copy.deepcopy(dict2)]
```

And you don't need to append dict1 and dict2 to list1 anymore.

Now your list1 contains a deepcopy of both dictionaries. So it doesn't matter if you clear or update any of those, the data in list1 is a deepcopy.

The full code looks like this now:

```
import copy
dict1 = {1:'a', 2:'b'}
dict2 = {24:'x',25:'y'}
list1 = [copy.deepcopy(dict1), copy.deepcopy(dict2)]

dict1.clear()
dict2.clear()

for l in list1:
    for keys, values in l.items():
        print('keys {}, values {}'.format(keys, values))
print('Dicts in list: ',len(list1))
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
keys 1, values a
keys 2, values b
keys 24, values x
keys 25, values y
Dicts in list:  2
[{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}, {24: 'x', 25: 'y'}]
```

I hope that helps!